# Upcasting in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, upcasting

Does spring boot support upcasting like we have in Core Java program.
For example:

`Parent p = new Child();`

How do we achieve this in spring boot?
*Note: As name suggest here, Child class extends Parent class.*

Comment: Spring Boot is a project, supported by several embedded frameworks, and as any other library, framework, or framework scaffolding project, Spring Boot is also built on top of core language ([Java, in this case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html)) specifications. So, it has **nothing** to do with type casting, per se. The question you're asking is about Java.. and not about Spring Boot.. and yes, it should be quite OK to do this implicit type widening. Also, it's not clear what is your problem.. where, exactly, you face an obstacle.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, we know upcasting advantages in run time polymorphism. On the similar note, I have just asked can we achieve upcasting advantages in spring boot without using 'new' keyword.